# regular expression to find a number matching a specific no of digits

Tags: regex

I am logging the time taken for completion in my web service. Now I am running a load test in Jmeter. I want to check those requests which took more than 10 sec to finish. Log is in the following format.

```
10:03:06 Time taken: 1 (ms)
10:03:07 Time taken: 12000 (ms)
```

I am trying to search for the second case but there are too many requests to check manually. Is there a way I can create a regular expression for finding values more than "Time taken: XXXXX".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically to be over 10 seconds, it has to be over 10000, which means it should have 5+ digits.

So it depends on the engine you are using, but something simple like this would work

```
\d\d\d\d\d+
```

Or like this:

```
[\d]{5,}
```